# Android: Using Earlier Versions of Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

I am using the [android-sdk-legacy](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk-legacy) SDK of Mapbox which is not supported. The access token from the Mapbox Website is not fetching the tiles.

Purpose: It supports clustered markers on the Mapbox.

Error: Could not fetch tiles because it could not validate Certificate and it was expired on 14Dec 2015.

Does it mean that this SDK can't be used at all? Also, can I use the SDK and host my own map server using [Mapbox-gl-native for Android](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/platform/android)

Please Help.

*Okay, this was the basic implementation of the Mapbox 0.7.4 version*

**EDIT**:

```
public class MainDiscoverFragment extends android.app.Fragment{

private MapView mapView ;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_discover, container, false) ;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    init(view) ;
    setInit() ;


    LatLng location = new LatLng(20.593684, 78.9628800) ;
    mapView.getOverlays() ;
    Marker marker = new Marker(mapView, "Abhinav Das", "Active 10hours ago", location) ;
    mapView.addMarker(marker);
}

private void init(View view) {
    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.discover_mapview) ;
}

private void setInit() {
    MapView mapView = new MapView(getActivity());
    mapView.setAccessToken(getResources().getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token));
    mapView.setTileSource(new MapboxTileLayer("mapbox.streets"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to use the Android Legacy SDK. Can you make sure you are using the correct style URL? I'm using the old SDK in one of my apps and it still works fine. Have you checked your account at Mapbox.com?

Heres how I setup the mapview within my app:

```
MapView mv = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mv.setCenter(new LatLng(29.7199489, -95.3422334));
mv.setZoom(17);
mv.setScrollableAreaLimit(scrollLimit);
mv.setMinZoomLevel(16);
mv.setMaxZoomLevel(21);
```

and within the layout I want to include the map I add this:

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            mapbox:mapid="{username}.{mapid}"
            mapbox:accessToken="Your access token here"/>
```

You can get your mapid from your map style within old [Mapbox editor](https://www.mapbox.com/editor/#style)

If you post some of your code, I might be able to spot any errors if any and i'll edit this answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Which version are you using? Are you sure you are using the [android-legacy-sdk](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk-legacy)?

Comment: The latest version and the last version that will be released is 0.7.4 which is what I've been using. I'd like to point out that the Android-GL SDK will be getting cluster markers down the road. You can read the [discussion on Github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/4693). I've added some code snippets to my answer to help you out.